# Android - How to display a local default image when url image jpg does not exists?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project where I am downloading information from https://www.themoviedb.org/ including a jpg file to be displayed in an activity. All is working as expected aside from time to time the jpg path is empty, resulting in a blank square instead of a poster.
Example of a constructed url when a jpg is available:
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3cvZAUVP0gjP0p54TOVXQ50fEyZ.jpg
Example of a constructed url when a jpg is NOT available:
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null

So I thought I could simply replace the null one with a local png file located in my drawable folder, however I have tried many different approaches, including stating that

```
if (poster.equals("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null")) {
                poster = "@drawable/noposter.png";
            }
```

However in the android monitor I can see it is recognized as a string.
I read the android developer's Accessing Resources in Code section however it doesn't cover my specific need.

I can't seem to display a default picture if needed.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Down below is the code working but displaying a blank square if no jpg is available:

```
public class GetMoviesInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Movies>> {

public InterfaceAsyncResponse delegate;
private final String LOGTAG = GetMoviesInfo.class.getSimpleName(); 
private final String API_KEY_HEX_NUM = "a valid key is here in my project";
private final String MOVIE_POSTER_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
private final String CHOSEN_MOVIE_POSTER_SIZE = "w185";

public GetMoviesInfo(InterfaceAsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected List<Movies> doInBackground(String... parameters) {

    if (parameters.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader inputReader = null;
    String moviesStr = null;

    try {

        final String BASEURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
        final String SORT_BY_KEY = "sort_by";
        final String APIKEY = "api_key";
        String sortedBy = parameters[0];

        Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASEURL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(SORT_BY_KEY, sortedBy)
                .appendQueryParameter(APIKEY, API_KEY_HEX_NUM)
                .build();

        URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());


        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();


        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer bufferStr = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            bufferStr.append(inputLine + "\n");
        }

        if (bufferStr.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        moviesStr = bufferStr.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error ", e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputReader != null) {
            try {
                inputReader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        return extractData(moviesStr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Movies> returns) {
    if (returns != null) {

        delegate.onTaskCompleted(returns);
    }
}

private String getReleasedYear(String dateReleased){
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateReleased));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}

private List<Movies> extractData(String moviesJsonString) throws JSONException {

    // Items being extracted
    final String MOVIES_ARRAY = "results";
    final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
    final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
    final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
    final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
    final String RELEASED_DATE = "release_date";
    final String POPULARITY = "popularity";

    JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(moviesJsonString);
    JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJson.getJSONArray(MOVIES_ARRAY);
    int moviesLength =  moviesArray.length();
    List<Movies> movies = new ArrayList<>();



    for(int i = 0; i < moviesLength; ++i) {

        // For each movie, the JSON object create a new movie object
        JSONObject movie = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String title = movie.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
        String poster = MOVIE_POSTER_BASE_URL + CHOSEN_MOVIE_POSTER_SIZE + movie.getString(POSTER_PATH);
        Log.i("TAG","From GetMoviesInfo_extractData: "+ poster);
        String overview = movie.getString(OVERVIEW);
        String voteAverage = movie.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE);
        String releasedDate = getReleasedYear(movie.getString(RELEASED_DATE));
        String popularity = movie.getString(POPULARITY);

        movies.add(new Movies(title, poster, overview, voteAverage, releasedDate, popularity));
    }
    return movies;
}
```

}

Comment: You can use either glide, fresco, or Picasso it totally depends on your ease. They provide placeholder function which can be used to place images before loading image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use picasso library for completing your goal, It is very simple to use i'm sharing the code.
for more information use this http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
> Picasso.with(context)
>     .load(url)
>     .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
>     .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
>     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works like a charm. 
I don't think I could thank you enough.